# Efficient decomposition algorithm for characters of symmetric groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, characters

Let $\chi$ be a rational character of $G:=S_n$, and we want to know whether it decomposes into irreducibles $\chi_\lambda$, for $\lambda\in\Lambda$, with $\Lambda$ given, as

$$
\chi=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} m_\lambda \chi_\lambda.\tag{$*$}\label{467474_star}
$$

We have a "blackbox" which computes for each $g\in G$ its value $\chi(g)=\mathrm{Tr}\ \rho(g)$ (where $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ with character $\chi$). And similar "blackboxes" for $\chi_\lambda$, $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Our goal is to find the $m_\lambda$s.

While naïvely one can take scalar products of $\chi$ and each $\chi_\lambda$ to determine the multiplicities $m_\lambda$, this is sub-optimal, as $\Lambda$ might be much smaller than the set of all irreducibles — in other words, the system of equations \eqref{467474_star} is over-determined.
So we can do better, just find a "good" submatrix for the linear system \eqref{467474_star}, i.e.
a set $M$ of $\lvert\Lambda\rvert$ elements $g\in M\subset G$ sufficient to evaluate $\chi(g)$ and $\chi_\lambda(g)$ on, so that the restriction of \eqref{467474_star} on $M$ has a unique solution. (Needless to say, different $g$'s in $M$ belong to different conjugacy classes of $G$.)

The question is, how to select $M$.

E.g. in the extreme case of $\Lambda=\{\lambda\}$ being a singleton, the question boils down to figuring out whether $\chi=\chi_\lambda$. That is, what is a minimal $M$ so that $\chi_\lambda$ is uniquely determined by restricting to $M$ ?
E.g. for irreducibles which are uniquely determined by their dimensions it suffices to have $M=\{()\}$. For irreducibles which are uniquely determined by the dimension up to multiplying with the sign character (e.g. the the $n-1$-dimensional subconstituent of the natural character of $G$), it suffices to take $M=\{(),(1,2)\}$.

On the other hand, for the most interesting for applications (namely, determining the character of a representation of degree $d$) case of $\Lambda$ containing all the irreducibles up to a given degree $d$, it's natural to try to take $M$ so that $|M|=|\Lambda|$, and $M$ consisting of permutations with cyclic structures corresponding to some $\lambda\in\Lambda$. (Corresponding
might mean being the same partition, or perhaps being the dual partition). This seems to work in few corner cases, but in general I don't know whether such a small, w.r.t. to $|\Lambda|$, $M$ even exists.

PS. An approach to doing such decompositions efficiently is oulined by S.Olver in [Representations of the symmetric group are decomposable in polynomial time](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12592) (among harder problems), but it's using GZ-bases and seems to be too much for such a question.

PPS. The case $\Lambda=\{\lambda\}$ would be helped by knowing that for sufficiently big $n$ one can have at most two irreducibles of the same degree.In general it's not true - e.g. $S_6$ has 4 different degree 5 irreducibles (they all can be distingushed by the value of $(1,2)$ on them, though).

Comment: Much of this question confuses me. It seems to me you are interested in questions of efficiency (in a computational sense, I guess), but then to understand how efficiently we can decompose $\chi$ into irreducibles, doesn't it heavily depend on how one is "given" $\chi$? Also, what could $M=\Lambda$ mean? $\Lambda$ is the collection of partitions of $n$, but $M$ is supposed to be a set of permutations.

Comment: $\chi$ is given by an oracle, as they say in CS. For instance $\chi$ is the character of a representation $\rho$, and we  have a way to compute $\chi(g)=\mathrm{Tr}\ \rho(g)$ for any $g\in S_n$

Comment: for $g\in M$, only the cyclic structure of $g$ matters as far as character values are concerned. Yes, strictly speaking, one should introduce a map $S_n \to \text{ unordered partitions of $n$}$ and talk about equality of $\Lambda$ and the image of $M$ under this map. Does this map have a name/standard notation?

Comment: @SamHopkins - I've edited to make it clearer, hopefully. Sorry for being too vague and brief.

Comment: So are we given $\Lambda$ as well?

Comment: Yes,  $\Lambda$ is given. A typical case is where all the irreds of degree at most $d$ , for some $d$, are specified by partitions in $\Lambda$

Comment: I'm still confused. If I want to find any given $m_{\lambda}$, I can just compute $m_{\lambda} = \langle \chi, \chi_{\lambda} \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)\overline{\chi_{\lambda}(g)}$. This has nothing to do with how many irreducibles are in the support of $\chi$. Is the point that you want to avoid this sum because it has $n!$ evaluations in it?

Comment: certainly - this sum can of course be compressed to the sum over the conjugacy class representatives, but this is still too inefficient (number of different irreds grows too fast with $n$). As I explained, to reconstruct many (all) irred. chars (not their values, but in the sense of determination by the partition of n) it suffices to check 2 values, not exp. many.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Isn't it clear that such an $M$ actually exists? For let $\{\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r\}$ be the irreducibles from $\Lambda$, and $g_1,\dots,g_h$ be representatives of the conjugacy classes. Then the matrix with $\chi_i(g_j)$ in position $(i, j)$ has rank $r$, thus we can pick $r$ columns from this matrix which has rank $r$, too. Of course, that's a pure existence argument, it doesn't tell how $M$ can be chosen for general $S_n$.

Comment: @PeterMueller - how about the case $r=1$, and $g_1=()$. Then you only know the degree of the irreducible, but that's usually not enough to figure out the one involved.  (I have fallen into this trap when I asked the question in the 1st place, too)

Comment: @PeterMueller: the $\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r$ span an $r$-dimensional subspace of the space of class functions, sure, but why should this subspace also be spanned by $r$ indicator functions of conjugacy classes? I expect that for a general group this will *not* be the case. Of course the symmetric group is special: in a general group we have no "canonical" bijection between irreducible characters and conjugacy classes, but for $S_n$ we kind of do.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Didn't you say (also in a comment above) that $\Lambda$ is **given** and is typically small compared to $h$? So I understand your question is about computing the $m_\lambda$'s without computing the expensive scalar products.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused about the paragraph on the case $\Lambda = \{\lambda\}$. If $\Lambda$ is *given* then we already know $\lambda$ and thus that $\chi$ is a multiple of $\chi_{\lambda}$, and we just need to, say, evaluate them at the identity to find the constant of proportionality.

Comment: @PeterMueller - indeed, I wasn't clear enough. I meant that a slightly more general question, deciding whether (*) has a solution, has the same linear algebra involved.


I have now changed the question to remove the promise that (*) is solvable, to begin with.

Comment: @KevinCasto - I've now edited the question to remove the promise that (*) is solvable. So the simplest problem is with $r=1$ to decide whether $\chi$ is the sum  of a number of copies of $\chi_1$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik So with $r=1$ and $\Lambda$ known: Set $m_1=\chi(e)/\chi_1(e)$. Then $\chi$ is a multiple of $\chi_1$ if and only if the generalized character $\chi-m_1\chi_1$ is $0$. Well, deciding whether a class function is the constant $0$ requires to know all its values in the representatives of the conjugacy classes. So I think in general this applies to $\chi-m_1\chi_1$ too.

Comment: @PeterMueller $\chi$ is a usual character, not an arbitrary class functon. Using all classes is an overkill, in general. But it's a good point, showing that 2 values might be not enough. As $\chi$ could be a sum of the trivial and the sign character, then even if have $\chi$ and $\chi_1$ of the same degree $(n-1)$, you need at least 3 different classes to evaluate $\chi$ on.

It seems that the special case, where $\Lambda$ contains all the characters up to a given degree $d$, is different from $r=1$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Even for $r=1$: Assume e.g. that $\chi$ has degree $n!=|S_n|$. With only this information, $\chi$ could be (among many other possibilities) a multiple of every irreducible character of $S_n$. So I guess to rule out even these $h$ ($=$ class number) cases requires to know $\chi(g_i)$ in each representative $g_i$ of the conjugacy classes.

Comment: @PeterMueller - note that (*) is not just a linear system, one has inequalities $m_\lambda\geq 0$ as well. The underlying polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$ is empty, or a singleton. In the former  case you need $|\Lambda|+1$ equations to show that there are no solutions, in the latter you need $|\Lambda|$ equations to specify the point uniquely. So your $|M|=|\Lambda|$ is right on point if we are promised that we are in the latter case. 

Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @PeterMueller - as soon as $d$ is big enough so that every irreducible may be a constituent, we can just use the usual scalar products. The interesting case is when $d$ is strictly smaller than the biggest degree of an irreducible.